# DBT snowflake utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 1031: invalid start byte

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I get the following error when I add fields (even commented out) into my query into DBT.
I am using DBT cloud, running off snowflake.

This runs fine - it even has the table from which I want the fields in the join at the bottom.

[image]

However, as soos as I put in the fields - even commented out, I get the error in the title.

[image]

Any one have any idea why this is happenning.

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  Did you per chance load data with IGNORE_UTF8_ERRORS=TRUE?  I've seen that setting cause this type of behavior.  Support advised reloading with this setting set to FALSE.  Albeit that was a couple years ago.

Comment: Are you getting the same issue through Snowflake UI and DBT, or is it just one vs. the other?

Comment: @GenDemo were you able to troubleshoot with the comments above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so in the end, I found out that somehow a non-ANSI character (like a deadspace) crept into my script between copying code to and from the DBT interface to SSMS. Still not sure how this happened. None the less, DBT has a python module that parses the text, and this python module was having an issue with that character.
So in the end, I simply had to retype my code... and then it worked.